# Cannot connect to Wi-Fi: Wireless toggle is not displayed

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi

I just bought a new laptop (Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 3, if it's relevant), it had no OS and I decided to install Mint. The problem is that I cannot get Wifi to work.
When I click the network manager icon on the taskbar, it only shows "Network Settings" and "Network Connections" buttons, there is no Wireless toggle.

I don't know what info you need so I will leave everything I can think of (or tried) here:

```
OS: Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon
Cinnamon version: 5.8.4
Linux Kernel: 5.15.0-767-generic
Processor: Intel Core i5 1335U
Graphics Card: Intel Corporation Device a7a1
```

Output to `lspci -nn | grep0280`

`00:14.3 Network Controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)`

Output to `iwconfig`:

`lo      no wireless extentions.`

There are also some `ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object ...`  these kinds of errors showing up when I turn on the laptop, but I read that it's not really a problem (I might be wrong)

I also tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, but the output says that it cannot resolve security.ubuntu.com and pacakges.linuxmint.com

Also tried `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`, same thing, security.ubuntu.com could not be resolved.

Output to `rfkill list`

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
             Soft blocked: no
             Hard blocked: no
...
```

(and then the same thing for “ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth” and “hci0: Bluetooth”

I don't know much (anything) about drivers. When I open Driver Manager without the USB stick in, it tells me that I am offline. When I have the USB stick in, it asks me if I want to mount installation media, I press it and type the password and it searches for drivers and tells me that no drivers are needed.

At this point, i don't really know what to try and I really want to try out this Linux thing, I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Please run `sudo dmesg | grep -i firmware` and add its output to your original post.

Comment: @telcoM Thanks for replying. I already solved the problem, guys at linux mint forum helped me out. Here's the link to the whole thing for people who might be having the same issue as I - https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=403248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved, here are the steps:

1. Use USB tethering to get internet connection temporarily
2. Install the latest 6.2 kernel with Update Manager
3. Reboot and Wireless toggle should appear

If you are having the same problem as me, you can check this [forum thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=403248) out